# ssh: check if a tunnel is alive

Tags: ssh, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

I have written a [small bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994928/bash-calling-a-scripts-with-double-quote-argument) which needs an ssh tunnel to draw data from a remote server, so it prompts the user:

```
echo "Please open an ssh tunnel using 'ssh -L 6000:localhost:5432 example.com'"
```

I would like to check whether the user had opened this tunnel, and exit with an error message if no tunnel exist. Is there any way to query the `ssh` tunnel, i.e. check if the local port 6000 is really tunneled to that server?

Comment: this might partially help "lsof -i | grep ssh"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is my test. Hope it is useful.

```
# $COMMAND is the command used to create the reverse ssh tunnel
COMMAND="ssh -p $SSH_PORT -q -N -R $REMOTE_HOST:$REMOTE_HTTP_PORT:localhost:80 $USER_NAME@$REMOTE_HOST"

# Is the tunnel up? Perform two tests:

# 1. Check for relevant process ($COMMAND)
pgrep -f -x "$COMMAND" > /dev/null 2>&1 || $COMMAND

# 2. Test tunnel by looking at "netstat" output on $REMOTE_HOST
ssh -p $SSH_PORT $USER_NAME@$REMOTE_HOST netstat -an | egrep "tcp.*:$REMOTE_HTTP_PORT.*LISTEN" \
   > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   pkill -f -x "$COMMAND"
   $COMMAND
fi
```

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in the above code. if [ $? -ne 0 ], the 0 should probably be a 1. the remote egrep will set $? to 0 if it successfully finds a match. In any event, I needed to use 1 to get this command to stop killing the existing tunnel every time I ran the command.

Answer (score 87):

Netcat is your friend:

```
nc -z localhost 6000 || echo "no tunnel open"
```

Comment: Wow, that's damn useful. I'm making a script that first of all creates a ssh tunnel, and I'm now using netcat to know when it's ready to accept connections. Works like a charm.

Comment: I would also suggest to use `nc -zv` to get `Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 6000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!` instead of no message upon successful connection

Answer (score 22):

Autossh is best option - checking process is not working in all cases (e.g. zombie process, network related problems)

example:

```
autossh -M 2323 -c arcfour -f -N -L 8088:localhost:80 host2
```

Answer (score 12):

This is really more of a serverfault-type question, but you can use netstat.

something like:

```
 # netstat -lpnt | grep 6000 | grep ssh
```

This will tell you if there's an ssh process listening on the specified port. it will also tell you the PID of the process.

If you really want to double-check that the ssh process was started with the right options, you can then look up the process by PID in something like

```
# ps aux | grep PID
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work on OS X, because netstat on OS X is different.

Answer (score 8):

Use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/). It's the tool that's meant for monitoring the ssh connection.

Answer (score 4):

We can check using ps command

```
# ps -aux | grep ssh
```

Will show all shh service running and we can find the tunnel service listed

Answer (score 3):

These are more detailed steps to test or troubleshoot an SSH tunnel. You can use some of them in a script. I'm adding this answer because I had to troubleshoot the link between two applications after they stopped working. Just grepping for the ssh process wasn't enough, as it was still there. And I couldn't use `nc -z` because that option wasn't available on my incantation of netcat.

Let's start from the beginning. Assume there is a machine, which will be called **local** with IP address 10.0.0.1 and another, called **remote**, at 10.0.3.12. I will prepend these hostnames, to the commands below, so it's obvious where they're being executed.

The goal is to create a tunnel that will forward TCP traffic from the loopback address on the remote machine on port 123 to the local machine on port 456. This can be done with the following command, on the local machine:

```
local:~# ssh -N -R 123:127.0.0.1:456 10.0.3.12
```

To check that the process is running, we can do:

```
local:~# ps aux | grep ssh
```

If you see the command in the output, we can proceed. Otherwise, check that the SSH key is installed in the remote. Note that excluding the username before the remote IP, makes ssh use the current username.

Next, we want to check that the tunnel is open on the remote:

```
remote:~# netstat | grep 10.0.0.1
```

We should get an output similar to this:

```
tcp  0  0  10.0.3.12:ssh  10.0.0.1:45988  ESTABLISHED
```

Would be nice to actually **see** some data going through from the remote to the host. This is where *netcat* comes in. On CentOS it can be installed with `yum install nc`.

First, open a listening port on the local machine:

```
local:~# nc -l 127.0.0.1:456
```

Then make a connection on the remote:

```
remote:~# nc 127.0.0.1 123
```

If you open a second terminal to the local machine, you can see the connection. Something like this:

```
local:~# netstat | grep 456
tcp  0  0 localhost.localdom:456 localhost.localdo:33826 ESTABLISHED
tcp  0  0 localhost.localdo:33826 localhost.localdom:456 ESTABLISHED
```

Better still, go ahead and type something on the remote:

```
remote:~# nc 127.0.0.1 8888
Hallo?
anyone there?
```

You should see this being mirrored on the local terminal:

```
local:~# nc -l 127.0.0.1:456
Hallo?
anyone there?
```

The tunnel is working! But what if you have an application, called **appname**, which is supposed to be listening on port 456 on the local machine? Terminate nc on both sides then run your application. You can check that it's listening on the **correct** port with [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/):

```
local:~# netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep appname
tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:456  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  2964/appname
```

By the way, running the same command on the remote should show sshd listening on port 127.0.0.1:123.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check do we have tunnel to example.com server
lsof -i tcp@localhost:6000 > /dev/null

# If exit code wasn't 0 then tunnel doesn't exist.
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
  echo ' > You missing ssh tunnel. Creating one..'
  ssh -L 6000:localhost:5432 example.com
fi

echo ' > DO YOUR STUFF < '
```

Answer (score 1):

stunnel is a good tool to make semi-permanent connections between hosts.

http://www.stunnel.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ssh in background, use this:

```
sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'
```