# How to set up an automatic (re)start of a background ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am a beginner user of linux, and also quite newbie at ssh and tunnels.

Anyway, my goal is to maintain a ssh tunnel open in background.

In order to do that, I wrote the following batch that I then added into crontab (the batch is automatically processed every 5 minutes during workdays and from 8am to 9pm).
I read in some other thread in stackoverflow that one should use autossh that will ensure the ssh will always be ok through a recurrent check. So did I....

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE="/root/Tunnel/logBatchRestart.log"
NOW="$(date +%d/%m/%Y' - '%H:%M)" # date & time of log

if ! ps ax | grep ssh | grep tunnelToto &> /dev/null
then
    echo "[$NOW] ssh tunnel not running : restarting it" >> $LOGFILE
    autossh -f -N -L pppp:tunnelToto:nnnnn nom-prenom@193.xxx.yyy.zzz -p qqqq
    if ! ps ax | grep ssh | grep toto &> /dev/null
    then
            echo "[$NOW] failed starting tunnel" >> $LOGFILE
    else
            echo "[$NOW] restart successfull" >> $LOGFILE
    fi
fi
```

My problem is that sometimes the tunnel stops working, although every thing looks ok (ps ax | grep ssh  > the result shows the two expected tasks : autossh main task and the ssh tunnel itself). I actually know about the problem cause the tunnel is used by a third party software that triggers an error as soon as the tunnel is no more responding.

SO I am wondering how I should improve my batch in order It will be able to check the tunnel and restart it if it happens to be dead. I saw some ideas in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998297/ssh-check-if-a-tunnel-is-alive), but it was concluded by the "autossh" hint... which I already use. Thus, I am out of ideas... If any of you have, I'd gladly have a look at them!

Thanks for taking interest in my question, and for your (maybe) suggestions!

Comment: I think you should have a look at serverfault.com. Search for `ssh` or `autossh` Example: http://serverfault.com/questions/159766/bash-script-with-permanent-ssh-connection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of checking the `ssh` process with `ps` you can do the following trick

create script, that does the following and add it to your crontab via `crontab -e`

```
#!/bin/sh

REMOTEUSER=username
REMOTEHOST=remotehost 

SSH_REMOTEPORT=22
SSH_LOCALPORT=10022

TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT=8080
TUNNEL_LOCALPORT=8080

createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -f -N  -L$SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:SSH_REMOTEPORT -L$TUNNEL_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo Tunnel to $REMOTEHOST created successfully
    else
        echo An error occurred creating a tunnel to $REMOTEHOST RC was $?
    fi
}

## Run the 'ls' command remotely.  If it returns non-zero, then create a new connection
/usr/bin/ssh -p $SSH_LOCALPORT $REMOTEUSER@localhost ls >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo Creating new tunnel connection
    createTunnel
fi
```

In fact, this script will open two ports

- port 22 which will be used to check if the tunnel is still alive
- port 8080 which is the port you might want to use

Please check and send me further questions via comments

Comment: Hi Marvin, if my answer helped you to solve the problem, vote on it and accept this answer - This will raise your and my reputation in stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried but encountered some problems:

*I am confused about ports; shouldn't the remote port be the same, whatevever the local one may be?

*also about the port : I have this option '-p $SOME_PORT' in the ssh command I used to use; does this override the $REMOTE_PORT or is this some additionnal port , and did you avoid to mention it on purpose?

Eventually, I get this on return from the (fixed) batch :
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [MyHostName]: Name or service not known. the hostname is correct, but it looks like it was unable to do the tunnel listener on port 22): Is there stg I miss?

Comment: Once again, I clicked too fast. And yes, it was helpfull since I am now a little less ignorant on this subject thanks to you!

Comment: The option `-p $SOME_PORT` is used to establish the ssh connection. Usually this is port 22 but with this option, you can change it. The statements like this `-L$SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:SSH_REMOTEPORT` are responsible for the tunneled ports, which must not be the same on local and remote side. So `-L10022:localhost:22` will tunnel the port 22 of your remote system to 10022 of your local machine. After that, you can access the server as well with `ssh localhost -p 10022` assuming that port 22 is the ssh port.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need bash for this!

Nowadays most linux boxes come with **[`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)** which has solid support for starting/stopping/restarting services with configurable conditions and timeouts.

1. As root create a `systemd` service unit:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/ssh-tunnel.service
```

2. Paste the following config into the new file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=ssh
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=5
StartLimitBurst=1

[Service]
# NOTE: you MUST start ssh *without!* the -f (forking) switch, 
# so that systemd can monitor it and detect when the tunnel goes down
Type=simple
# forward *local* port 80 to port 8088 on the remote host
ExecStart=ssh username@myremote-host.com -N -R 8088:localhost:80
# send an exit signal to the SSH master process that controls the tunnel
ExecStop=ssh arh -O exit -R 8088:localhost:80
# see: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=
TimeoutStartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

# TODO: set the user name here; root will be used if unset
# make sure the user has the correct ssh key or otherwise 
# explicitly pass the key with `ssh -i /path/to/key/id_rsa   
User=my-user-name

# TODO: for debugging only; remove once you get the service working
StandardOutput=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Enable and start the service unit:

```bash
# make service start on every boot (after network is up)
sudo systemctl enable ssh-tunnel

sudo systemctl start ssh-tunnel
```

4. (Optional) Check the status of your service:

```bash
systemctl status ssh-tunnel
```

##### How does this work?

`StartLimitIntervalSec` configures the interval for counting service starts. If a service is started more than `StartLimitBurst` times *within* this interval, it is not permitted to start any more. `TimeoutStartSec` configures the max time that `systemd` will wait for the service to start before it is considered to be in failed state.

With the configuration above if the SSH tunnel goes down, for example, because of temporary network glitches, `systemd` will wait for 10 seconds, and then restart the tunnel.

This approach is reliable, configurable and achieves the same result as the scripts given in the other answers or utilities like [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh), but in a generic way that can be used with any other tool.

The key here is to start SSH in *foreground* mode (i.e. do NOT send it to background with `-fn` switches) so that `systemd` can monitor whether the service is still alive and restart it in case of failure.

#### See also:

- [systemd:TimeoutStartSec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=)
- [Self-healing services with systemd](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/systemd-automate-recovery)

Answer (score 1):

*(I add this as an answer since there is not enough room for it un a comment)*

Ok, I managed to make the batch run to launch the ssh tunnel (I had to specify my hostname instead of localhost in order it could be triggered) :

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/root/Tunnel/logBatchRedemarrage.log"
NOW="$(date +%d/%m/%Y' - '%H:%M)" # date et heure du log


REMOTEUSER=username
REMOTEHOST=remoteHost

SSH_REMOTEPORT=22
SSH_LOCALPORT=10022

TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT=12081
TUNNEL_SPECIFIC_REMOTE_PORT=22223
TUNNEL_LOCALPORT=8082

createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -f -N  -L$SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:$SSH_REMOTEPORT -L$TUNNEL_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:$TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT $REMOTEUSER@193.abc.def.ghi -p $TUNNEL_SPECIFIC_REMOTE_PORT
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo [$NOW] Tunnel to $REMOTEHOST created successfully >> $LOGFILE
    else
        echo [$NOW] An error occurred creating a tunnel to $REMOTEHOST RC was $? >> $LOGFILE
    fi
    }

## Run the 'ls' command remotely.  If it returns non-zero, then create a new connection
/usr/bin/ssh -p $SSH_LOCALPORT $REMOTEUSER@193.abc.def.ghi ls >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo [$NOW] Creating new tunnel connection >> $LOGFILE
    createTunnel
fi
```

However, I got some immediate message (below) when the tunnel is running and when cron tries to lauch the batch again... sounds like it cannot listen to it. Also since I need some time to get a proof , I can't say yet it will successfully restart if the tunnel is out.

Here's the response to the second start of the batch.

> bind: Address already in use channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen
>   to port: 10022 bind: Address already in use
>   channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 8082 Could not
>   request local forwarding.

Comment: the address in use message you get is because you removed from your script the part that checks if your tunnel is already running. `pgrep -fl $SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:$SSH_REMOTEPORT` would reveal that the ssh from the first run is still running.