# Check if SSH tunnel is open and close it from other terminal

Tags: networking, ssh, centos

I don't know anything about ssh (or bash) but I'm opening a tunnel like this (random IP's in my example):

```
ssh -L50000:120.134.4.156:50000 cadmin@34.564.234.64 -g
```

How can I

1. Check from another terminal that the tunnel is open and if it's closed/non existent open it.
2. Close the tunnel from another terminal if tunnel is open.

I have been reading here but I don't know how to use this answer: [ssh: check if a tunnel is alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998297/ssh-check-if-a-tunnel-is-alive)

Thanks for all help,
Cris